# Difficulty understanding code to count the number of inversions using BIT

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MX = 100;
int n,a[MX*2],bit[MX];

void add(int x, int y){
    for(;x<=n; x+=-x&x) bit[x]+=y;
}
int query(int x){
    int s= 0;
    for(;x>0; x-=-x&x) s+=bit[x];
    return s;
}
int main(){
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int ans = 0;
    cin >> n; n*=2;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for(int i = n-1; ~i; i--){
        ans+=query(a[i]-1);
        add(a[i],1);
    }
    cout << ans;
}
```

I dont understand how the query and add contribute to finding the number of inversions in an array. If someone can help explain this to me that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bad obfuscated code. Do not spend your time to understand it.

Comment: ... and if you want to understand it anyway, print out the bit patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I hope you understand how `add` and `query` work in `BIT`. If not, think of `BIT` like a blackbox which stores prefix sums for count of elements `1, 2, ..., n` in array `A`. For example, `A[3] = count(1) + count(2) + count(3)`. `add(x, y)` increments `count(x)` by `y` and `query(x)` returns the sum `count(1) + count(2) + ... + count(x)` i.e., the prefix sum till element `x`.

Elements at index `i` and `j` form an inversion if `i < j` and `arr[i] > arr[j]`. But the above code reads it the other way; `j > i` and `arr[j] < arr[i]` (this save an extra call to `query`).

Now suppose the array is `{3, 4, 1, 5, 2}` and `{2, 5, 1}` have already been inserted in the `BIT`. Then `query(1) = 1`, `query(2) = 2`, `query(3) = 2`, `query(4) = 2` and `query(5) = 3` (remember to think of `BIT` as a blackbox that stores prefix sums). Notice when index `i` is pointing at element `4`, all the elements that have already been inserted having indices `j1, j2, ..., jk` are all `> i` so now we only need to count the number of elements `< 4` which is the prefix sum till `3` which we get by calling `query(3)`.